# 3rd party assembly nagging when debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I use a third-party dll in my application developed in Visual Studio 2010 and C#. When I debug my application by clicking the "Run (Debug)" button in Visual Studio 2010, that dll can detect and know that I am in so-called "development mode".

When I go the bin/debug folder and double click my application's exe file, the dll doesn't complain.

How can I configure so when I run the application in "development mode", the dll still thinks that it is executed in normal mode?

Answer (score 5):

It's probably checking `Debugger.IsAttached`.

Solution: Don't use the debugger.
Real solution: Buy the library.

Comment: Thank you. The background story is a bit tricky. We did buy the license. But it was a release license rather than a development license and they didn't tell us clearly about that. So the dll works fine in release model and final product but just complains in development model. They are asking for double price for the development + release dll, which is over our budget.

Comment: What product is this? Let us know which product to avoid!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what the library does, it may be possible to separate out your application into separate components, one of which uses the library and does not run in debug mode.  This will allow you to debug your application while still using the library.

Pro: What you are trying to do is definitely in violation of the license.  This solution might not be in violation of the license.

Con: This will make it impossible for you to debug your use of the library.  All it accomplishes is to allow you to debug the rest of your application by separating off the library usage.

Con 2: This will probably makes your application more difficult to maintain.  It may also impact performance.